# How to detect a screen touch that already exists when activity is created?

Tags: android

I have an app that is used outdoors, in all conditions. These are on rooted B&N Nook tablets running Android 2.1. They have optical touch detection, not pressure, so a large raindrop on the screen can "disable" the device, because it's being detected as a press, and then all other presses are not detected.

Part one: in the activity being used, I manually detect long (10 second) screen presses, consistent with a raindrop beginning a blocking press. I use dispatchTouchEvent() for this and it's fine.

Part two: So then I open a new activity and actually circle the rain drop and tell the user "wipe up this rain drop". The new activity opens fine, and I can successfully draw circles anywhere I please.

The trouble is the new activity does not receive any touch events for that very first press... the long press that hasn't stopped yet. Not getting a "new" ACTION_DOWN is understandable... I already grabbed that. If I lift my finger though, there's no ACTION_UP either. *After* lifting the initial press, every works fine: I can tap the screen, instantly a circle is drawn around the spot, and it will move if I drag my finger, so no problems there.

How do I get the **initial** press, the one that brought me here, that still exists? It must some sort of polling API, not event, since I really want the current state and I know the event is already sucked up. To be clear, NO events are coming out of dispatchTouchEvent() until I first take my finger off the screen (even the off does not create a detectable event).

(I *could* grab the coordinates from the prior activity and pass it... but the trouble there is the rain drop could slide around during the 10 second wait period. And I would rather the activity be self contained in doing its job.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can (although I've never tried).  I'm pretty sure the touch events are canceled out as soon as the new Activity is opened.

The approach that you may decide instead is to either use the Framgents API or simply open a new View on top of the View that's being touched.

The View that's receiving touch events will continue to do so until one of these events happen:

1. The method `onTouchEvent()` returns `false`.  If it returns `false` at any point, it will stop receiving touch events all together.  Meaning, if you return `false` in an ACTION_MOVE action, you will *not* receive an ACTION_UP action.
2. You receive an ACTION_CANCEL which denotes the gesture has ended.  Usually it means the touch left the view bounds, but it could be a number of reasons.
3. You receive an ACTION_UP which means the last touching finger lifted from the View.

Views in the back will always receive touch events as long as Views in the front return `false` for the actions which most do by default.  So if you just pop up a new View on top of the View that's recording the touches, just keep recording and pass the draw coordinates to the top View.

Comment: As I get a bit further along, I realize that the missing ACTION_UP is problematic. That is my notification that the drop has been wiped up. And it didn't happen in the previous view. I wonder if there's a state issue where the OS won't send an ACTION_UP without first sending a ACTION_DOWN. Or perhaps before I open this activity I need to clear an input/event queue of some sort. Could I somehow send an ACTION_CANCEL in the first activity?

Comment: A full gesture is started with an ACTION_DOWN and end with an ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL (all other actions are optional). You won't get touch events unless you get an ACTION_DOWN and return `true` indicating your View wants to handle this.

Comment: When you transition to another activity, the root view is changed, so the old `View` you were touching is gone.  You *might* get an ACTION_CANCEL if this happens, but I think it's more likely the system just cuts the touch event chain off and stops sending actions.  When this happens, you won't get touch events in the new Activity because you need to start the chain again with an ACTION_DOWN (which is why it starts working again when you lift your finger and put it back down).

Comment: And I can't return true on the ACTION_DOWN when I process it... for all I know (then) it could be valid. I only find out 10 seconds later when it hasn't been released that it's a problem.

Any thoughts on cancelling the existing gesture, or hmmm, I wonder if I could pass a reference to the previous view somehow.

Comment: Returning `false` on an ACTION_DOWN is basically saying your View doesn't handle gestures at all which is not the case here. It's detecting the down motion then waiting 10 seconds. So you could for example start your 10-second timer on ACTION_DOWN, cancel it on ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL if the timer did not fire. Move the circle around on ACTION_MOVE.  Return true for all instances.